# No matter what I do, Ubuntu 15.04 does not recognize HP LaserJet 1020

Tags: 15.04, printing, hp, hplip

I have been using Ubuntu and Linux in general since 2001 and this is the first time that I have not been able to install my printer.

Approx a month ago I upgraded the system from 14.10 to 15.04 doing clean install of `/` partition, but not touching `/home` partition. After booting into the system, the printer did not work. So I tried to install it by plugging it like dozens of times before, but it could not be recognized.

I tried HPLIP installation by downloading HPLIP for 64bit Ubuntu and when it came to `hp-setup` part, I picked to install the USB printer, but HPLIP could not find it.

[image]

I switched multiple USB ports without success.

I even tried foo2zjs, but its local settings web page told me that I need proprietary driver to use this printer.

I am clueless as I have not idea how to install this printer which is 110% supported.

`lsusb` sees the printer and outputs

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:2b17 Hewlett-Packard LaserJet 1020`

Comment: Yes, work well on Windows laptop.

Comment: Have you tried the install cd it came with?

Comment: or equivalent software from online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this URL (https://mark911.wordpress.com/2014/10/31/how-to-install-printer-drivers-for-hp-laserjet-1020-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-without-needing-access-to-openprinting-org-website/) solves the issue. The printer return to life and I was able to print test page.

Namely, HPLIP is buggy and we should not use it. Instead we should use CUPS via foo2zjs.

I will give this a good test over the next few days and weeks and will update the answer if this solution is not long term.